# CSS: The font is bold, but it shouldn't be

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div id="e_ticket_info" class="e_ticket_font" runat="server" Visible="False">
    <p>
      Some text.
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.e_ticket_font {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

The HTML code is on content page, which is inside master page.

The issue is - the text is bolded out, but it shouldn't be.

How can I can get rid of it?

Comment: Can you recreate it in a fiddle? What font are you using, if you inspect it in the console what styles is it inheriting ? If all else fails  `font-weight: normal !important;` should do the trick

Comment: probably you have some css elsewhere, because that snippet alone would not make it bold, see here http://jsfiddle.net/JRfex/

Comment: I've solved it. The issue was:

font-family: Arial Black, Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

that is: Arial Black, that is: Black!

With this:

.e_ticket_font 
{
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

The font is not bolded out, that is it's normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dipesh's answer is correct. I'll just add a bit explanation. CSS is cascading style sheet, means the style for any element/class/id can be mentioned at multiple places and applied in the order in which they are included. In your case, some other style seems to override your style to make it bold since your snippet will not make it bold.

Considering this, as a general best practice, always target the specific elements if you are not sure if it's class will be styled somewhere else or not.

Thus, `.e_ticket_font  p {...` is prferable than `.e_ticket_font {...`. If there are multiple paragraphs and you want only some of them to be different, then again use classes/ids, like

```
.e_ticket_font p#heading {...
.e_ticket_font p#content {...
.e_ticket_font p.specialpara {
```

and so on.

Another way to make it sure is to apply css inline for that element, but this should **not** be used generously for many elements as it affects the "structure should be separate than presentation" principle

Comment: do you mean you have tried giving an id to that para and still .e_ticket_font p#whateverid {... is not working?

Comment: @tesicg good to know you solved your problem and Thanks for opening my account of accepted answers :)

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
.e_ticket_font p {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

because you are not targetting `p` tag.

Comment: This would fix it if the problem is a rule elsewhere (with a less specific selector) that makes the `p` element bold. But it would be important to find that other rule and consider whether it makes sense. Otherwise, it can cause other odd effects in the future.

Comment: just to add to that, it does not need to be a less specific selector, it would also do if it was exactly the same

Comment: @tesicg then that means you have more rules somewhere else that have that effect, the css you posted does not seem to be complete, did you try to inspect your site with developer tools (f12 in firefox for example)?

Comment: What can I do if I find something? How can I fix it?

Comment: you need to find the rule that is responsible for making your text appear bold, when you found it you just use the exact same selector and write a new rule that sets it to the desired value, keep in mind that you overwriting this value has to occur after the declaration of the rule it is overwriting ;)

Comment: I've solved it. The issue was:

font-family: Arial Black, Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

that is: Arial Black, that is: Black!

With this:

.e_ticket_font 
{
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

The font is not bolded out, that is it's normal.

Comment: post your own fix as an answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div runat="server" Visible="False">
    <p class="e_ticket_font">
      Some text.
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.e_ticket_font {
    font-weight: normal !important;
}
```

Comment: why you are editing original `html`...??? instead check my answer...you can do this by targetting `p` tag

Comment: but that make normal font for every p tag which is there inside that div

Comment: well there is one more...what if that same class appied to more than one `p` tag but OP wants only this `p` which is inside `e_ticket_font` parent//

Answer (score 0):

or (for each) element below .e_ticket_font:

```
.e_ticket_font * {
  font-weight: normal; 
}
```

i advice a **rare use of !important** in case of runaway bubbling your DOM

but mind of the selector detail.. if there is any css selector which describes the object on a directer way like...

```
.e_ticket_info#e_ticket_info { 
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

...css will pick that one with privileg!

Answer (score 0):

try inline css because if you don't know if there are other css classes are specified in masterpage for `<P>`

something like:

```
<div runat="server" Visible="False">
    <p style="font-weight: normal;" >
      Some text.
    </p>
</div>
```

it will work for sure, then you can check for other css references for `<P>`